# className not working in VueJS method

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue.js

I want to change the classNames of all elements with the class on "link". I am using a method which is called via a click action on the element. I tested out getting a length from the function and that works fine but adding a class does not. Anyone know why?

**HTML**

```
<div id="app">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#" class="link" @click="myFunc">Link text 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="link" @click="myFunc">Link text 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="link" @click="myFunc">Link text 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var app = new Vue({
el: '#app',
methods: {
  myFunc: function(event){

      // works
      var ElLength = document.getElementsByClassName('link').length;
      console.log('ElLength = ' + ElLength);

      // does not work
      document.getElementsByClassName('link').className += " hullaballoo";

    }
  }
});
```

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/kf0vwtgs/)**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
document.getElementsByClassName('link')
```

returns you an array-like object of html element, and `.className` is an attribute of each element in this object, maybe you can try this:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('link')[0].className += " hullaballoo";
```

instead.

Comment: Thanks, is the a way to add the class to all those element, maybe using a forEach loop?

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to change the class on all the links with your current code.

What's I'd suggest instead is:

```
event.currentTarget.classList.toggle('hullaballoo');
```

`event.currentTarget` will always be the link you clicked.

If you want them all "hullaballoo" when one is clicked you can do:

```
<a v-for="link in 3" 
   href="#probably-actually-want-a-button"
   @click.prevent="allSelected = !allSelected"
   :class="{ hullaballoo: allSelected }">
   Link {{ link }}
</a>
```

However, having to do this is not taking advantage of Vue. You're thinking too DOM like. Ideally you'd want to change these classes based on some state your'e in. You'd need to clarify your question more to get a better answer, though.

Comment: Thanks but I want all the links to change not just the currentTarget. I do know there are easier ways of accomplishing this in Vue but I'm finding Vue lacks easy ways to modify the dom. So I'm trying to gauge how I can perform tasks that are easy in jQuery but difficult in Vue. I want to use Vue in a future project and I'm hoping to replace jQuery with Vue but I think I might have to still use jQuery for dom manipulation.

Comment: It's a lot easier to modify the DOM with Vue since it's directly tied to data. You can do `<a v-for="link in 3" @click.prevent="allSelected = !allSelected" :class="{ selected: allSelected }">Link {{ link }}</a>`.

Comment: but you see it's kind of dumb without a rhyme or reason.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer will return all matching elements in the document.

If you just want to get those in your component, you can do like this:

```
this.$el.getElementsByClassName('link')
```

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-el